# Magento 2 pager not working custom collection

Tags: magento2, product, pager

In My custom Collection Pager not working
**`Index.php`**

```
<?php

namespace Test\CustomProduct\Block\Index;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    protected $_collectionFactory;
    protected $_productsFactory;

   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
      \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productsFactory,
       array $data = []
   ) {
       $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
       $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
       $this->_productsFactory = $productsFactory;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }

   public function _prepareLayout()
   {
       return parent::_prepareLayout();
       $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Best Seller'));

       if ($this->getBestSellerData()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager','vlc.history.pager')->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,15=>15,20=>20));
            $pager->setLimit(5)->setShowPerPage(true);
            $pager->setCollection($this->getBestSellerData());
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getBestSellerData()->load();
        }
        return $this;
   }
   public function getPagerHtml(){
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }


   public function getBestSellerData(){
       $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
                    ->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
              ->setPageSize(100)
                    ->setPeriod('month');
                    //->setPeriod('day');
                    //->setPeriod('year');

       return $collection;
   }

   public function getMostviewdData(){
        $currentStoreId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $collection = $this->_productsFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(
            '*'
        )->addViewsCount()->setStoreId(
                $currentStoreId
        )->addStoreFilter(
                $currentStoreId
        );
        $items = $collection->getItems();
        return $collection;

    }

    public function getNewProductCollection(){
        $collection = $this->_productsFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setPageSize(5);
        /*Add you filters here as suggested by Amit and and Manashvi */
        return $collection;
    }



}
```

**`.phtml`**

```
<?php /* Best Seller Collection */?>
    <?php 
        $bestSeller =  $block->getBestSellerData();
        //echo count($bestSeller);?>
        <h1>Best Seller Collection.....</h1>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($bestSeller as $value) {?>
                <li><?php echo $value['product_name'];?></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
<?php /* Best Seller Collection */?>
<?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
        <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Any error in this? also check in html sometime pagination are set hidden.

Comment: No error ........ No Hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `return parent::_prepareLayout();` after that code is not run.

change this

```
public function _prepareLayout()
   {
       return parent::_prepareLayout();
       $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Best Seller'));

       if ($this->getBestSellerData()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager','vlc.history.pager')->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,15=>15,20=>20));
            $pager->setLimit(5)->setShowPerPage(true);
            $pager->setCollection($this->getBestSellerData());
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getBestSellerData()->load();
        }
        return $this;
   }
```

to

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
   {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
       $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Best Seller'));

       if ($this->getBestSellerData()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager','vlc.history.pager')->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,15=>15,20=>20));
            $pager->setLimit(5)->setShowPerPage(true);
            $pager->setCollection($this->getBestSellerData());
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getBestSellerData()->load();
        }
        return $this;
   }
```

Now here is you solution

```
namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Block;

class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
      protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    protected $_collectionFactory;
    protected $_productsFactory;

   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
      \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productsFactory,
       array $data = []
   ) {

       $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
       $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
       $this->_productsFactory = $productsFactory;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }

   protected function _prepareLayout()
   {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
       $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Best Seller'));

       if ($this->getBestSellerData()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager','vlc.history.pager')->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,15=>15,20=>20));
            $pager->setLimit(5)->setShowPerPage(true);
            $pager->setCollection($this->getBestSellerData());
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getBestSellerData()->load();
        }
        return $this;
   }
   public function getPagerHtml(){
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
    public function getBestSellerData(){

      $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;

      $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 10;
       $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
                    ->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
                    ->setPeriod('month')

                   ;
   $bestSeller = $collection->getColumnValues('product_id');   

   $newCollection = $this->_productsFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in',$bestSeller))->setPageSize($pageSize)->setCurPage($page);   

       return $newCollection;
   }


}
```

phtml code

```
<?php /* Best Seller Collection */?>
    <?php 
        $bestSeller =  $block->getBestSellerData();
        //echo count($bestSeller);?>
        <h1>Best Seller Collection.....</h1>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($bestSeller as $value) {
                ?>
                <li><?php echo $value->getName();?></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
<?php /* Best Seller Collection */?>
<?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
        <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
```

[Reference](http://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-add-pagination-custom-collection/)

[GitHub](https://github.com/kingsatti/magento2_bestseller)

Comment: Now page title comming but no pager

Comment: @Magento2 i added the solution for you it is tested and working.

Comment: Thanks it's working how to get all information about product like image qty etc...

Comment: @Magento2 use `->addAttributeToSelect('*')` in collection already updated the code.

Comment: i have some issue in custom page collection https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200820/element-with-id-history-pager-already-exists

Comment: I have implemented same code and my collection size is 52 and limit is 5. But after click on 5 page or Next page next page is not displaying like 6 7 8 9 10 is not showing.

Comment: Hey @QaisarSatti I'm using the same code for my custom table but my pagination is not working because in the page query, I'm getting "http://website_url/controller/index/index/?p=2?p=1" like this, How can we remove extra query..