# Element with ID '.history.pager' already exists

Tags: magento2, page

i got this error while load new product collection in my custom cms page

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
   {
      parent::_prepareLayout();
       $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Best Seller'));

       if ($this->getCollection()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager','newproduct.history.pager')->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,15=>15,20=>20));
            $pager->setLimit(5)->setShowPerPage(true);
            $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getCollection()->load();
        }
        return $this;
   }
   public function getPagerHtml(){
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }

    public function getCollection(){
      $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
      $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 100;
        $collection = $this->_productsFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setOrder('entity_id','desc')
        ->setPageSize(20)
        ->setPageSize($pageSize)->setCurPage($page);
        return $collection;
   }
```

Error

**`Error filtering template: Element with ID 'newproduct.history.pager' already exists.`**

How to fix this issue

Comment: Try change name of created block to any another, it is should help.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting

Comment: i tried to change this name newproduct.history.pager but still error only

Comment: Text of error is changed?

Comment: Yes it changed...

Comment: @Magento2 maybe you are calling the pager two time in you phtml that is causing this error.

Comment: I have New product best seller & most view so i added with diffrent block  with different id then i got this error

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by following code,

> by  changing `sales.order.history.pager` to
>   `'sales.order.history.custompager`

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    if ($this->getOrders()) {
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager::class,
            'sales.order.history.custompager'
        )->setCollection(
            $this->getOrders()
        );
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getOrders()->load();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Hope it helps to someone.

Comment: what are sales.order.history.custompager?